# Querying documents based on text filters for the parent

Tags: performance, mongodb, schema

I have three collections in my system (A,B,C). A has a ref of B collection and B collection has a ref of C collection. The C collection has a field - `keywords` which is an array of strings.

```
A -> B -> C
```

The problem is that I want to query all `A` documents that have matching keywords in their respective `C` collections.

I can query C first by applying `$in` filter for the `keywords` field and then get B and ultimately all the A docs, but that seems inefficient to me. Is there are way to get this done faster?

**Update:**

**Complete Example**
I have a collection called `Campaign` each campaign has multiple `subscriptions`. A `Campaign` can also have a set of `keywords` (String Array). I want to be able to query all the subscriptions whose campaigns match the queried `keywords`.

**Campaign Schema:**

```
mongoose.model 'Campaign', new mongoose.Schema
    name:
        type: String
        required: true
    program:
        type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId
        required: true
        ref: 'Program'
    days:
        type: Number
        required: true
    keywords:
        type: [String]
    commitment:
        type: Number
    performance:
        type: Number
    isEnabled:
        type: Boolean
        default: true
```

**Subscription Schema**

```
 SubscriptionSchema = new mongoose.Schema
        client:
            type: String
            required: true
        startDate:
            type: Date
            required: true
        campaign:
            type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId
            required: true
            ref : 'Campaign'
        totalCredits:
            type : Number
            required: true
        usedCredits:
            type : Number
            required: true
            default: 0
        created:
            type: Date
            default: Date.now
        data:
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
    model = mongoose.model 'Subscription', SubscriptionSchema
```

**Update 2**
Another solution could be - Create a virtual property to query the keywords from its Campaign, but that will only be efficient if I could index on virtual properties.

Comment: This kind of reference schema obviously low the performance because it has to query collection by collection as you see. Add index to reference fields will help some. If possible, store all information in collection A directly.

Comment: If I store it in A then there are a lot of As which will have redundant data [Keywords].

Comment: Redesign your schema to denormalize information about C into A. More specific advice can't be given without more knowledge about the data and use case.

Comment: @wdberkeley Added more details to the question.

Comment: You could denormalize some or all campaign info into subscriptions. Keep the campaign info you need when you pull a subscription in the subscription (like keywords) and the more detailed info in a separate campaign doc that you can look up by reference. Then if you find one matching subscription by keyword you can jump to the referenced campaign if needed.

Comment: The keywords are like 100-200 per campaign. Nd each campaign could have a lot of subscriptions. Wouldnt it be too redundant to store the same keywords for multiple subscriptions?

Comment: And how would it effect update operations?

Comment: @wdberkeley Your solution makes much more sense to me now. The only problem is that how do I maintain these keywords for subscriptions? Is someone updates the keywords for a campaign I will have to write code to update it on each and every subscription

Comment: That is the price of denormalization - if you update a denormalized piece of information, every document containing it must be changed. The tradeoff of disk space (redundant storage of data) for faster and easier retrieval is generally worth it, but the tradeoff between easier reads and easier updates is one you need to weigh carefully based on your application's requirements.

Comment: Perfect. A lot of other people might benefit from this conversation if you just summarize and post it as answer.